# Dask: How to efficiently distribute a genetic search algorithm?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

I've implemented a genetic search algorithm and tried to parallelise it, but getting terrible performance (worse than single threaded). I suspect this is due to communication overhead.

I have provided pseudo-code below, but in essence the genetic algorithm creates a large pool of "Chromosome" objects, then runs many iterations  of:

1. Score each individual chromosome based on how it performs in a 'world.' The world remains static across iterations.
2. Randomly selects a new population based on their scores calculated in the previous step
3. Go to step 1 for n iterations

The scoring algorithm (step 1) is the major bottleneck, hence it seemed natural to distribute out the processing of this code.

I have run into a couple of issues I hoped I could get help with:

1. How can I link the calculated score with the object that was passed to the scoring function by `map()`, i.e. link each `Future` holding a score back to a `Chromosome`? I've done this in a very clunky way by having the `calculate_scores()` method return the object, but in reality all I need is to send a `float` back if there is a better way to maintain the link.
2. The parallel processing of the scoring function is working okay, though takes a long time for `map()` to iterate through all the objects. However, the subsequent calls to `draw_chromosome_from_pool()` run **very** slowly compared to the single-threaded version to the point that I've not yet seen it complete. I have no idea what is causing this as the method always completes quickly in the single-threaded version. Is there some IPC going on to pull the chromosomes back to the local process, even after all the futures have completed? Is the local process de-prioritised in some way?
3. I am worried that the overall iterative nature of building/rebuilding the pool each cycle is going to cause an enormous amount of data transmission to the workers. The question at the root of this concern: what and when does Dask **actually** send data back and forth to the worker pool. i.e. when does Environment() get distributed out vs. Chromosome(), and how/when do results come back? I've read the [docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html) but either haven't found the right detail, or am too stupid to understand.

Idealistically, I think (but open to correction) what I want is a distributed architecture where each worker holds the `Environment()` data locally on a 'permanent' basis, then `Chromosome()` instance data is distributed for scoring with little duplicated back/forth of unchanged Chromosome() data between iterations.

Very long post, so if you have taken the time to read this, thank you already!

```
class Chromosome(object):    # Small size: several hundred bytes per instance 
     def get_score():
          # Returns a float
     def set_score(i):
          # Stores a a float

class Environment(object):   # Large size: 20-50Mb per instance, but only one instance
         def calculate_scores(chromosome):
             # Slow calculation using attributes from chromosome and instance data
             chromosome.set_score(x)
             return chromosome

class Evolver(object):
    def draw_chromosome_from_pool(self, max_score):
        while True:
            individual = np.random.choice(self.chromosome_pool)
            selection_chance = np.random.uniform()
            if selection_chance < individual.get_score() / max_score:
                return individual   

    def run_evolution()
         self.dask_client = Client()
         self.chromosome_pool = list()
         for i in range(10000):
             self.chromosome_pool.append( Chromosome() )

         world_data = LoadWorldData() # Returns a pandas Dataframe
         self.world = Environment(world_data)

         iterations = 1000
         for i in range(iterations):
             futures = self.dask_client.map(self.world.calculate_scores, self.chromosome_pool)
             for future in as_completed(futures):
                  c = future.result()
                  highest_score = max(highest_score, c.get_score()) 

             new_pool = set()
             while len(new_pool)<self.pool_size:
                 mother = self.draw_chromosome_from_pool(highest_score)
                  # do stuff to build a new pool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each time you call the line

```
futures = self.dask_client.map(self.world.calculate_scores, self.chromosome_pool)
```

you are serialising `self.world`, which is large. You could do this just once before the loop with

```
future_world = client.scatter(self.world, broadcast=True)
```

and then in the loop

```
futures = self.dask_client.map(lambda ch: Environment.calculate_scores(future_world, ch), self.chromosome_pool)
```

will use the copies already on the workers (or a simple function that does the same). The point is that `future_world` is just a pointer to stuff already distributed, but dask takes care of this for you.

On the issue of which chromosome is which: using `as_completed` breaks the order that you submitted them to `map`, but this is not necessary for your code. You could have used `wait` to process when all the work was done, or simply iterate over the `future.result()`s (which will wait for each task to be done), and then you will retain the ordering in the chromosome_pool.

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful.

Comment: Could you explain how the Chromosome objects distributed by map() are managed between the local process and workers? Specifically, if Environment.calculate_score() modifies a Chromosome object (e.g. sets an attribute), how does that manifest as an IPC? I am trying to figure out whether it is better for calculate_score() to update the Chromosome passed to it directly, or return a tuple of values and then have the local process iterate through the pool and apply the updates centrally.

Comment: Using map() in the form suggested above yields "TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration", however "for c in self.chromosome_pool: futures.append( (self.dask_client.submit(Environment.calculate_scores, future_world, c)" is basically equivalent and does work.

Comment: I think this form of `map` should work. Generally, Dask should not work by mutation but by returning new results. In python, there is no robust way of knowing whether the value/contents of some variable have changed or not.